# OpenBVE not starting in Trusty

Tags: 14.04

Why doesn't OpenBVE work in Trusty(14.04)? When i launch it it says the program has crashed. Please help me it crashes each and everytime

Answer (score 2):

Because there is a bug. 
This one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openbve/+bug/1273393
which is confirmed and hopefully someone is working (will work) on it and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I think I was able to solve it under Lubuntu 14.10.

Operating `openbve`, I installed mono by [this](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin) advice. According to my system, after installing `openbve` pulse audio server installation, I have a problem with SDL libraries, so you can check if something is missing from the list:

```
libSDL-1.2
libSDL_image-1.2
libSDL_mixer-1.2
libSDL_ttf-2.0
libSDL_net-1.2
libsmpeg-0.4
libSDL_gfx
```

I hope to not miss anything :)